# Cannot Decrypt RSA encrypted Key

Tags: c#, security, encryption, rsa, encryption-asymmetric

Long story short, I'm using DES and I'm encrypting a password using RSA for key exchange, the password does not exceed 16 characters
the problem is when i encrypt the key, the encrypted size becomes too big for me to decrypt
here's my rsa encrypt and decrypt code:

Encrypt:--i've been trying the localpwd as "asd"

```
    byte[] plaintext = utf8.GetBytes(localpwd);
    byte[] ciphertext = rsaservice.Encrypt(plaintext, false);
    string cipherresult = Convert.ToBase64String(ciphertext);
```

then i print the encrypted key on the textbox and try decrypting

```
    byte[] ciphertext = utf8.GetBytes(filetest.Text);
    byte[] plain = rsaservice.Decrypt(ciphertext, true);
    string plaintext = utf8.GetString(plain);
```

i get "the data to be decrypted exceeds the maximum for this modulus of 256 bytes".
i tried increasing the key size to be able to encrypt and decrypt larger key sizes, but increasing the key just increases the size of the encrypted data resulting in the same error
please help!!!

Comment: I'm not seeing the reverse of `ToBase64String()`

Comment: I'm using the utf8 encoding to get convert to bytes nad back to string again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
//byte[] ciphertext = utf8.GetBytes(filetest.Text);
  byte[] ciphertext = Convert.FromBase64String(filetest.Text);
```

Comment: WOW never thought it would be that simple, you sir have just saved my life :D thank you

Comment: is it possible for me to use unicode? I'm trying to send over a network stream and i can't do it for Base64 strings

Comment: I DO NOT KNOW HOW TO THANK YOU ENOUGH